# Update QGraphicsItem without redraw

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have `QGraphicsItem` that represents a graph inside a grid and is updated continuously.
For performance reasons I would prefer to just draw what has been added since the last update instead of redrawing it completely. Something like this:

**Regular paint function:** (for rescales)

```
def paint(self, painter, style, *args, **kwargs):
    painter.setBrush(self._brush_transparent)
    painter.setPen(self._pen_background)
    painter.drawPolyline(self._point_pairs)
```

**Paint function that only adds the last point:**

```
def _paint_update(self, painter, x, y):
    painter.setBrush(self._brush_transparent)
    painter.setPen(self._pen_background)
    painter.drawPolyline(self._point_pairs[-1:], QPointF(x, y))
```

However I don't know how to redirect the `paintEvent` or get the Widgets painter to do it manually.

Comment: 1. use smaller units of items and only update the affect ones; 2. (not sure if available in pyqt), push a dirty area to be repaint, and in paintEvent() get the affected area need to be redrawn.

Comment: what triggers a redraw, is it the addition of points? so if no points added, then no need to redraw?